# How do I "park" a heavy, wheeled ship on an incline?

Tags: space-engineers

I have a large planetary mining rig with four 5x5 wheels. It drives fine. I've got the settings for power, friction, dampening and strength set up in such a way that it handles fairly well when driving. However, if I get on any kind of incline, the ship will not stop moving. When I press the handbrake it slows down but never hits 0 km/h. Parking doesn't work either, it just keeps rolling. (Read: Not slipping. Rolling.)

Does anyone know how to get a large/heavy ship to reliably park on an uneven surface?

Comment: Would you consider it cheating to add horizontal thrusters and use inertia dampening?

Comment: So pressing P once doesn't bring it to a complete stop?

Comment: @Philipp That would work, obviously adding bulk and complexity and I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: @BadAtPHP Not on an incline, and even less so when I leave the cockpit (bug?).

Comment: You need a brick https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqAqe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to take the wheels off the ground using pistons, unfortunately that only works up to a certain weight as they are very unreliable themselves and tend to break under pressure.
Currently operating a rover with north of 7K Tons and 12 5x5 Wheel Suspension and I’m yet to successfully deploy the 12 pistons.
Basically impossible to stop it in uneven terrain without the use of thrusters.

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing. It's tricky to not roll past your target while deploying the pistons, and like you said, weight is a problem. I hope a fix comes along soon™.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is use a rotor to swing down a landing gear, then 'dock' to the ground. To get going again, I 'undock' the gear, then swing the rotor up. Then I be off.

Answer (score 2):

You can reliably stop a wheeled vehicle by using the "Safety Lock Override" function on the suspension, which will lock the wheels in place.  This can be associated to an action bar function by grouping the wheels and executing the action on the group.  Unfortunately, the game will also lock suspension settings while the wheels are in safety lock, so if you want to modify suspension settings while stopped you can use this on one set of wheels and modify the other.